# Haxe - Looping animation movieclips from SWF library causes memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, haxe, openfl

I create `var` for my movieclip that has long animation like this:

```
public var swftest = Assets.getMovieClip ("library:MovieclipA");
```

and then I add it on screen like this:

```
public function animation_test()
{
    s_container.addChild(swftest);
}
```

for some reason it causes memory leak, as if Haxe doesnt know how to handle looping animation in a movieclip... If I do `swftest.gotoAndStop(1);` it wont anymore cause memory leak... If I let `swftest` just play, it will cause crash in about 50 seconds as it takes more and more memory.

Here is snippet from `project.xml` where I enable loading assets from `library.swf` if it helps to solve this problem:

```
<!-- classpath, haxe libs -->
<source path="src" />
<haxelib name="openfl" />
<haxelib name="swf" />
<haxelib name="actuate" />

<!-- assets -->

<library path="Assets/library.swf" type="swflite" preload="true" generate="true" />

<assets path="Assets" rename="assets" exclude="openfl.svg|*.swf" />
<icon path="Assets/openfl.svg" />
```

Help **sincerely** appreciated!

Comment: Solved it ... Of course when I have been trying to solve this for hours and I ask from Stackoverflow I solve it when I get back to it... from `project.xml` changed `type="swflite"` to `type="swf"` .... fml so many things I tried and it was that simple!

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question and accept it a bit later so the question is marked as solved: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by switching `type="swflite"` to `type="swf"` from `project.xml`.

Here is part of my project.xml that lets me use .swf library:

```
<haxelib name="swf" />

<library path="Assets/library.swf" type="swf" preload="true" generate="true" />

<assets path="Assets" rename="assets" exclude="openfl.svg|*.swf" embed="true" />
```

Now it works just fine, no memory leak.

Comment: It would be great if you'd submit an issue to https://github.com/openfl/swf/issues